# Tracking anonymous users on Mixpanel's Explore

Tags: mixpanel

I understand I can attach an alias to a previously anonymously identified users, but how can I explore their behavior before they sign up? (they don't appear on Mixpanel's Explore until the `identify` API is called)

Thanks

Comment: Have you found out an answer for this?

Comment: Yes, see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is to call `mixpanel.identify()` (with no args) when the app starts for the first time.

Then when the user registers you call alias and identify with your internal id.

Comment: Then you won't know what's going on until they signed up.

Comment: @gerbil You know everything what the user does, what actions she makes. What you don't know is the info you request for at registration, like name, email etc. So such a user would show up as Anonymous User in the People / Explore.

Answer (score -1):

The way to do it is using mixpanel funnels.

Comment: I think this does not really answer the question. For example, what if you want to see the users in People/Explore?

Comment: You can't as the user is not identified so it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You can, since the user is indeed identified, if you call `mixpanel.identify()`. It totally makes sense. You just don't know the name, email etc. till the users registers.